# Durandal compose to load viewmodel dynamically

Tags: .net, durandal

I have a requirement to load a viewmodel in a div dynamically based on which menu button has been clicked.

i have this in my html

```
<div data-bind="compose: activeScreen"></div>
```

and this is my Javascript

```
define(['services/logger', 'durandal/system','require'],
    function (logger, system, require) {       
        var title = 'Development Plan';
        debugger;

        var VM1 = require("signoff");

        var vm = {
            activate: activate,                        
            activeScreen : VM1
        };            


        return vm;      



        function activate() {
            return false;
        }     
});
```

but..... No surprise, it doesnt work !!

please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make activeScreen a observable (e.g: ko observable) and on menu click change its value. Durandal relies on knockout js a lot (or on its own observable lib), so play with knockout to understand how to works , then jump into Durandal.

Btw, if you only have to load a html in compose, you dont explicitly load it via require, just pass the full path to activeScreen, compose binding will handle the loading and caching etc.